# Vim-vsnip and Vim-EasyComplete integration issue

Tags: json, vim, vim-plugin

I am using vim-vsnip for snippets creation and using Vim-EasyComplete for auto completion. The issue is that when the initial preview box opens the preview box shows the function name(prefix) along with the description but I only wnat the function name(prefix)to display not the description

The snippet json file looks like this

```
{
  'and' : {
         "Prefix" : "and",
         "Description" : ".....",
         "Body" : [.......]
           }
}
```

> 

I tried changing the snippets file but it did not work and I have been looking into the vim-easycomplete documentation but did not find anything